# Booting into Ubuntu from a Macbook

Tags: dual-boot, mac, macbook

I already have installed Ubuntu and have already used it but for some reason it now is not showing up when I select a boot device. I believe it’s because I uninstalled Windows which I installed from the Bootcamp tool in Mac OS because it would not boot into windows and would only boot into the GNU command line.

Comment: Boot from a live USB and use the boot repair tool https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair. You may have to reinstall GRUB in the internal HDD (warning: while this works on a regular computer,I don't know if it may cause a problem with the MacOS bootloader. If you want to be very safe, reinstall ubuntu instead).

Comment: How did you "uninstall Windows"? From within MacOS? Then MacOS must have corrupted the Ubuntu bootloader